# How to print raw text request of POST from Ruby's HTTMultiParty?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, httparty

I"m using `HTTMultiParty` to upload a PDF to a very finicky `API`. I think `HTTMultiParty` isn't getting the headers quite right, but can't figure out how to print out the raw `HTTP` request so that I can verify whether that is the case. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Not familiar with `HTTPMultiParty`, but in `net/http`, you can use `request.to_hash` to check the headers it sends.

Comment: I need more detail than a hash - this is a legacy SOAP API that's been turned into REST, and some of the formatting requests are _super_ weird. Thanks for the recommendation, though.